# How to parse JSON which include list of objects

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I need to parse JSON to an object which includes list of objects. So there`s my [JSON](https://pixabay.com/api/?key=11670931-bb66861cd97f09841fe543406&q=yellow%20flowers&image_type=photo&pretty=true).

I created two classes for it. There are them

```
public class Picture
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string pageURL { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public string previewURL { get; set; }
    public int previewWidth { get; set; }
    public int previewHeight { get; set; }
    public string webformatURL { get; set; }
    public int webformatWidth { get; set; }
    public int webformatHeight { get; set; }
    public string largeImageURL { get; set; }
    public int imageWidth { get; set; }
    public int imageHeight { get; set; }
    public int imageSize { get; set; }
    public int views { get; set; }
    public int downloads { get; set; }
    public int favorites { get; set; }
    public int likes { get; set; }
    public int comments { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string userImageURL { get; set; }
}
public class PicturesByTopic
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int totalHits { get; set; }
    public List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
    public PicturesByTopic()
    {
        Pictures = new List<Picture>();
    }
}
```

I tried to parse them in two ways:

```
static PicturesByTopic GetPicturesByTopic(Message message)
{
    var topic = message.Text;
    var url = $"https://pixabay.com/api/?key={PicturesAPIKEY}&q={topic}&image_type=photo&pretty=true";
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    string response;
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        response = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }

    PicturesByTopic picturesByTopic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PicturesByTopic>(response);
    return picturesByTopic;
   
}
```

And the second variant:

```
static List<PicturesByTopic> GetPicturesByTopic(Message message)
{
    var topic = message.Text;
    var url = $"https://pixabay.com/api/?key={PicturesAPIKEY}&q={topic}&image_type=photo&pretty=true";
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    string response;
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        response = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }

   
    var wrappedText = @"{ ""Prop"": " + response + " }";

    var jsonData = JObject.Parse(response);

    List<PicturesByTopic> RetsProperties = new List<PicturesByTopic>();

    foreach (var prop in jsonData["Prop"])
    {
        RetsProperties.Add(new PicturesByTopic
        {
            total = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(prop.First.ToString()),
            totalHits = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(prop.First.ToString()),
            Pictures = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Picture[]>(prop.First.ToString())
        });
    };

    return RetsProperties;

    
}
```

But I can`t take correct parsing object by two of them. So any thoughts about this? Hope, my explanations
was clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the first variant. Your solution is not working because the json has different names than your class. You should rename:

```
public List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Picture> hits { get; set; }
```

I am not sure if JsonConvert would work with `Hits`, but if it does you should use it due to naming conventions.

**EDIT:** If you want to keep using Pictures as a property name you can use the JsonProperty attribute, like this:

```
[JsonProperty("hits")]
public List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
```